# Django ForeignKey TemplateSyntaxError and ProgrammingError

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

This is are my models i want to relate. i want for collection to appear in the form of occurrence.

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    collection_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.collection_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'collection'
        ordering = ('collection_name',)

class Occurrence(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=True)
    reference = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, null=True, blank=True, unique=True),
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
         db_table = u'occurrence'
```

Every time i go to check the Occurrence object i get this error

```
 TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/hotiapp/occurrence/
 Caught an exception while rendering: column occurrence.collection_id does not exist
 LINE 1: ...LECT "occurrence"."id", "occurrence"."reference", "occurrenc..
```

And every time i try to add a new occurrence object i get this error

```
 ProgrammingError at /admin/hotiapp/occurrence/add/
 column occurrence.collection_id does not exist
 LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "occurrence" WHERE "occurrence"."coll...
```

What am i doing wrong? or how does ForeignKey works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have not updated your database table definition since adding the ForeignKey. `syncdb` doesn't do this for you, as the documentation clearly states. You need to update the SQL manually, or use a tool like South.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you mean

```
collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, null=True, blank=True, unique=True),
```

Nullable and Unique?  This may not be possible in some databases.

Generally, the unique constraint doesn't seem to make much sense here.

Are you trying to force a 1-to-1 relationship?  Use the OneToOneField.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField